# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, property found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the error: "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, property found". I'm not sure what is wrong with this way of providing the information via a property

The relevant code of MainApp.py

```
from constantsconfig import _Const

if not os.path.exists(_Const.CONFIG_DIRECTORY): //error happens on this line
    os.makedirs(_Const.CONFIG_DIRECTORY)
```

The relevant code of constantsconfig.py

```
import os

def constant(f):
    def fset(self, value):
        raise TypeError
    def fget(self):
        return f()
    return property(fget, fset)

class _Const(object):
    @constant
    def MAIN_CRON_JOB_ID(self):
        return "MAIN_CRON_JOB_ID"
    @constant
    def DOWNLOAD_PHOTOS_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES(self):
        return 15
    @constant
    def BASE_API_URL(self):
        return "http://example.com/file.php"
    @constant
    def API_KEY_RASPBERRIES(self):
        return "fasd79f97fsfa80f809f809fasd890fsda76fds5f54ds465fdas456"
```

The error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/_Data_/MainApp/RaspberriPi/_App/mainapp.py", line 192, in <module>
    if not os.path.exists(_Const.CONFIG_DIRECTORY):
  File "C:\_Data_\MainApp\RaspberriPi\_App\venv\lib\genericpath.py", line 26, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, property found
```

Comment: Try `_Const().CONFIG_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: mmm, that did the trick, I'm not (yet) that familliar with python, so simple once you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the class `_Const`. This is wrong, you should be using an *instance* of the class `_Const`.

For example,

```
const = _Const()
if not os.path.exists(const.CONFIG_DIRECTORY):
    os.makedirs(const.CONFIG_DIRECTORY)
```

Or better yet,

```
const = _Const()
try:
    os.mkdir(const.CONFIG_DIRECTORY)
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```